# RegEx to match a pattern

Tags: regex

The problem I'm having is, I don't want to match to have a comma preceding the first match number..

Ex: `"1,2,3 <?>"` and `"0,9,1,2 <?>"`

What I have now is `@"\d,\d,\d\s*<?>"` and It returns this `"1,2,3 <?>"` and `"9,1,2 <?>"`. It shouldn't get the `"9,1,2 <?>"` because it has a `0,` in front... How do I exclude this match?

Comment: Which language are you running?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [beginning of string `^` and end of string `$` anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and escape the `?` metacharacter.

```
@"^\d,\d,\d\s*<\?>$"
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wZ0tM0/1)

Comment: Try using the multiline modifier `@"(?m)^\d,\d,\d\s*<\?>$"`

Comment: Ok this is weird if run this @",?\d,\d,\d\s*<?>" it picks up the comma and the ones with out comma in front, so that means it sees the comma and their is no spacing issue.. I just don't get it.. if i run @",\d,\d,\d\s*<?>" it picks up only the comma's in the front?